# How do I defined subnets in Bicep such that the parent Vnet has a reference and that I can dependOn the subnet deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-bicep

I have a situation where I need to define my subnets in the `properties.subnets` field of the parent virtual network otherwise I get the ['InUseSubnetCannotBeDeleted' problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58919472/199)

**Option 1 - Defined inline**

However if I define my subnets directly in the `properties.subnet` array (see below) then they are not created as children and I cannot seem to create a reference them as a resource for when I want to create a `dependsOn` reference for another resource.

```
resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-08-01' = {
  // ... other fields
  properties: {
    subnets: [
      // How can I get a reference to these that I can 'dependOn'?
      {
        name: 'subnet-1'
        // ... other fields
      }
      {
        name: 'subnet-2'
        // ... other fields
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Option 2 - Defined separately**

```
resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-08-01' = {
  // ... other fields
  properties: {
    subnets: [
      subnet1 // Gives a circular reference error
    ]
  }
}

resource subnet1 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2021-08-01' = {
  parent: virtualNetwork
  name: 'subnet-1'
  // ... other fields
}
```

I have tried defining the subnets as separate resources and then reference the resources in the `properties.subnet` array but, since subnets need a reference to the parent virtual network proeprty, Bicep complains about a circular reference.

It seems that ARM templates can use textual references using the name of the subnet in `properties.subnets` whcih could get around the circular reference, however Bicep does not allow this.

So how do I defined my subnets so that I can simulteneously satisfy the virtual network's required to have a reference to the subnets in `properties.subnets` as well as be able to have a resource reference that I can use in `dependsOn` clauses?

Comment: are you defining your vnet inside a module ? Also which resource need the dependson ?

Comment: Also you could just create a `dependsOn` on the `virtualNetwork` resource.

Comment: @Thomas As far as I can tell though there is no guarantee the child resource will actually be created when the parent is created - so depending on the parent wouldn't be watertight

Comment: If you define your subnets within the vnet resource it will work for sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72622826/4167200

Comment: OK thanks Thomas, there is definitely some 'magic' to how subnets are created using the `properties.subnets` approach then. I'm going to assume this holds-off resolving the parent virtual network until the subnets are also created.

Comment: There is some [discussion on the Bicep Github as well on this](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/7513)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work. Bicep builds it without errors, but I have not tried to deploy it.

```
resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-08-01' = {
  name: 'myvnet'
  location: 'swedencentral'
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        '10.0.0.0/20'
      ]
    }
    subnets: [
      {
        name: 'subnet-1'
        properties: {
          addressPrefix: '10.0.0.0/24'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource subnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2022-01-01' existing = {
  name: 'myvnet/subnet-1'
  scope: resourceGroup()
}

resource storage 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-09-01' =  {
  name: 'mystorage'
  location: 'swedencentral'
  dependsOn: [
    subnet
  ]
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
}
```

Comment: Hmm nice idea but I don't think there is any guarantee that the subnet is existing when the symbolic name is created and [looking at this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/existing-resource#troubleshooting) it seems that this could be a cause of problems - I tried it out and it gave an error although it was not an explicit `NotFound` error ...

Comment: `dependsOn` is only for resources that are provisioned in the same template/file.  Not for existing resources.

Comment: They are actually created in the same template.

Comment: @PeterL-MSFT if you update the above to the `parent`, `name` reference which has an implicit dependency on the virtual network I will happily mark this as the answer - at the moment it doesn't wait for the virtual network to deploy